# Can a Disregarded Entity has a loss on schedule C deduct a loss on the personal return?

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company, schedule-c

I have a single member LLC and chose to be a Disregarded entity. If I have a gain of $500 on my sch C, I have to pay SE tax. But what if I have a $500 loss instead? Do I have to carry it forward? Can I combine it with all my income and claim a loss on my 1040?

Answer (score 1):

LLC has nothing to do with your question.

Active activity loss on Schedule C will only flow to form 1040 line 3 if all the investment is at risk (and then it reduces your total income).

If not all the investment is at risk then the losses may be limited.

See the [instructions for schedule C line 32](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040sc#en_US_2022_publink24329wd0e2203), including the explanation of the "at risk" concept.